# Grails: How to define a domain property rendered on views but not persisted?

Tags: grails, gsp, grails-domain-class

I have this domain classes, let's say:

```
class Person {
  String name
  Integer age
  //car data that needs to be shown and filled in views 
  //but not persisted in Person class
  String model
  String color

  static afterInsert = {
    def car = new Car(model: model, color: color)
    car.save()
  }
}

class Car {
  String model
  String color  
}
```

What I need is to show in my `Person` views (`create` and `edit`) the model and color properties that are defined inside `Person` class but these doesn't have to be persisted with this class. These data, `model` and `color`, have to be persisted using the `Car` domain class maybe using the `afterInsert` event. In other words, I need to save data from a domain class using the views from another domain class.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [transients](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/transients.html) on properties you want GORM to ignore, for example

```
class Person {

  static transients = ['model', 'color']

  String name
  Integer age
  //car data that needs to be shown and filled in views 
  //but not persisted in Person class
  String model
  String color
  ..
}
```

Just curious but is there a reason you're not using associations

```
class Person {
  ..
  static hasMany = [cars: Car]
}

class Car {
  ..
  static belongsTo = [Person] 
  static hasMany = [drivers: Person]
}
```

.. or composition

```
class Person {
  Car car
}
```

or simply data binding with multiple domains

```
//params passed to controller
/personCarController/save?person.name=John&age=30&car.model=honda&car.color=red

//in your controller
def person = new Person(params.person)
def car = new Car(params.car)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have tried this but the model and color fields are not rendered in the views.

Comment: Just curious - is there a reason you don't use associations, composition or simply [data binding with multiple domains](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#dataBinding)

Comment: Yes, I think there's a relation that could be defined, but for my problem it is not very necessary . What would be great is to check if a car exist and retrieve its data maybe using its id and if it doesn't exist create a new car through a popup window.

Comment: if you just want data binding on multiple domains, i've included an example at the end